# Passing a custom data type to Silverlight RIA service class methods

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, ria

I have few methods that accept more than 20 parameters. This is a Silverlight RIA service class. 
I am trying to refactor the code and am interested in knowing if there is a way to pass in a custom data type.

So for example:

```
public partial class MyContext : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<MyConnectionString>
{
  //other functionality omitted for simplicity

   public IQueryable<Foo> GetFoo(int param1, string param2, string param3, string param4)
   {
      //foo stuff
   }
}
```

Now, can I create a custom struct for example:

```
public struct WrapParams
{
  //which will actually contain param1,param2, param3 , param4
}
```

so that I can just pass WrapParams (from the client side) as a parameter to my method?

Is this possible? If so how can I achieve it? (I was not successful in getting this working)

Answer (score 0):

You can use method like this in RIA Services

```
public IQueryable<Foo> GetFoo(Dictionary<string,object[]> params)
   {
      //foo stuff
   }
```